# Transfer Serilog to Seq or file using USB connection to mobile phone?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, adb, serilog, seq-logging

I am using Xamarin (`Xamarin.Android`, but also looking for a solution for `Xamarin.iOS`) on Android and Serilog. Currently I am logging to a file liks this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug() // minimum log level that will be passed to sink
    .WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "applog.json"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

I then pull `applog.json` manually from my android phone or emulator using `adb` and ingest it to Seq.

Instead of this manual procedure I'd like to send the log data directly to Seq. However my mobile phone is not on the same network as my computer which runs Seq. Instead my phone is connected to my computer using an USB cable (Android debug mode). Is there any way to send the log data via USB to Seq on my computer? Can I configure some kind of network via USB?

Comment: Sounds like an awesome article if you are able to figure it out!

Comment: @Saamer Doubt there is a direct solution for that. One could setup logging to a remote Seq installation though, that's available from both networks. Guess that is what I will be doing.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No ): I ended up using the web api of Seq to send it there over the network.